# .htaccess redirect in drupal that excludes node edit page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, drupal

Currently I have the following htaccess redirect rule that detects any path that looks like

mysite.com/node/xxx and redirects it to a .php script that, in turn, finds the URL of the page and redirects the user to it (e.g. mysite.com/page/page.html)

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(page=(31|1))?$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^node/?$ /? [L,NC,R=301]
 RewriteRule ^(../)?node/([0-9]+)$ noderedirect.php?nid=$2 [L]
```

What I want, however, is that also when user accesses

`mysite.com/node`
or
`mysite.com/node?page=xxx`

they get redirected to the main page

BUT

when they access

`mysite.com/node/xxx/edit`

the rule doesn't get activated.

I tried several options (stopping at the one above) and so far I have this, but it still enables users to access `mysite.com/node?page=xxx` (all the other conditions are working fine.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Your regex won't match `node/xxx/edit`. So it won't rewrite to noderedirect.php, what do you want it to do when you have a `/edit` at the end?

Comment: I just want it to go to that page, and not to do anything. but when it's /node/xxx or /node or /node?page=xxx i want it to redirect to noderedirect.php

Answer (score 0):

> I just want it to go to that page, and not to do anything. but when it's `/node/xxx` or `/node` or `/node?page=xxx` i want it to redirect to noderedirect.php

If you want it to always go to the noderedirect, then try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+node\?page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /node/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^node/?$ /noderedirect.php [L]
RewriteRUle ^node/([0-9]+)/? /noderedirect.php?nid=$1 [L]
```